# Accessing remote VLC interface on home network via Safari browser on iPhone

Tags: networking, macos, vlc-media-player, iphone, safari

I'm running a VLC on Mac OS X Yosemite and I want to control it over phone via home WiFi network. I configured remote interface on VLC following the [instructions found on the net](http://sybu.co.za/wp/vlc-setup/):

1. The web interface is active
2. The password is set
3. I can access the VLC web interface locally by going to: `http://localhost:8080/` as explained in the instructions
4. When I run a designated application, like *[VLC Remote](http://hobbyistsoftware.com/vlc-more),* it correctly shows the local IP of the Mac that is running the VLC with the web interface active. Furthermore, the app connects to that Mac/VLC with no problems.

## Problem

I would like to access the *mobile web interface* that VLC [appears to have](https://wiki.videolan.org/Control_VLC_via_a_browser/) on a Safari browser on the iPhone without any additional app but when I type my *local IP address* and port in format `http://X.X.X.X:8080`, the Safari page stays blank and does not load.

### Summing up:

1. VLC web interface appears to be running as I can access it on the same mac that I'm running VLC
2. I **can** connect to the remote VLC web interface via a designed iPhone app (tested with *VLC Remote*)
3. I **can't** connect to the remote VLC web interface via a phone browser

Needles to say, I'm very much interested in addressing the third point. Any suggestions on what to do what to check will be much appreciated.

Comment: you need to encode URLs that we need to be able to read rather than click using backticks, otherwise you get http://127.0.0.1 when you want us to be able to actually read `http://127.0.0.1` [seems to be impossible to show you a backtick in comments, see my edit on your post for the styling]

Comment: @Tetsujin The URLs were only examples, I didn't want to share any particular address.

Comment: but we cannot read them. put backticks round to *show* examples. Like we cannot read your comment because the automatic encoding kills what you wrote & makes it a clickable link instead

Comment: @Tetsujin No problem, it seems it was edited already.

Comment: Yes. I edited your post, but still no-one can tell what you actually wrote in your comment, because of the auto-encoding. Hence, the backticks...

Comment: @Tetsujin understood, I added a dot after the last digit for the local IP.